# Efficient way to read chunks of a file at a time

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filestream

I'm trying to use the [low level multipart upload for s3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingLLmpuDotNet.html), using `HttpClient.PutAsync`.   These are large files, so I'm attempting to upload them in 5MB chunks.

What I'm not sure of is, how to best provide an arbitrary chunk with a specific length to `PutAsync`?   I'd like to upload a bunch of these chunks at once, so loading each 5mb chunk into memory isn't really an option -- it should be streamed from disk as needed.

For example, to upload 5mb starting at position 5*1024*1000, I can do something like:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    stream.Seek(5*1024*1000);
    // limit length here to 5mb??
    var content = new StreamContent(stream);
    var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(url, content);
    // etc..
}
```

But of course this will upload the entire remainder of the file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that the minimum part size for each part (except the last, of course) in a multipart upload is actually 5MB.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I updated the post to avoid confusion.

Comment: I am not conversant in .net, so I have no answer, but I expect you will find it impractical to avoid reading the chunks into memory.  You need to at least *have* read through the entire chunk in order to calculate the `Content-MD5:` request header that ensures accurate transmission of each part.  It's technically optional, but actually critical, since it's the only guarantee that S3 will absolutely reject a chunk that has been corrupted in transit in any way.

Comment: Importantly, too, you needn't send more than perhaps 8 parts simultaneously -- beyond a certain threshold, you will gain no more throughput, because you will saturate your connection.  I have written my own multipart uploaded and I can saturate a 100 Mbit/sec connection with about 8 parts in parallel, depending on which S3 region I'm uploading to.  (More parallel parts are needed to saturate the link when the distance is larger.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a byte array read, and send byteArray content to the PutAsync method.

Eg:

```
Stream.read(buffer, offset, count)
```

And then do

```
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
var response = await client.PutAsync(uri, byteContent);
```

You can also try the `BufferedStream` class which allows you to set a buffer size to the stream.

Haven't tried it, but should mostly work.

Comment: Unfortunately this would involve reading the entire chunk size (2mb) into memory...